# Passing method to component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have been trying to work out how if its possible and how to pass a method from the main page into a component in Blazor.

I have a simple razor page, which contains a component with a button.  I want to pass the onclick method from the razor page to the button in the component

Note: I do not need this method to return anything void is fine.  I just need to be able to call a method from the main page in a button on the component.  I only added int here as a guess since it was complaining about T

## Page

```
@page "/test"
@using Testing.Client.Model;
@using System.Threading;

<TestMethodPassing ExternalMethod="@btnClick"></TestMethodPassing>

@code {

    public Action<int> btnClick(){ return 1;}

}
```

## Model for component

```
public class TestingMethodPassingModel : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    protected Action<int> ExternalMethod { get; set; }
}
```

## component

```
@inherits TestingMethodPassingModel;
@using testing.Client.Model;
@using System.Threading;


<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ExternalMethod" autofocus>External button</button>


@code {


    }
```

## Errors

The above code gives me the following error

> Gives me No overload for 'btnClick' matches delegate 'Action'

I tried doing type T as well and that failed as Blazor cant for some reason find the reference for type T

## Update Note

Working example pieced together from the answers.   [PassingMethodToComponent](https://github.com/LindaLawton/BlazorExamples/tree/master/src/PassingMethodToComponent)

Comment: I don´t know razor so well, but I´m pretty sure an onclick-delegate doesn´t expect an int-argument.

Comment: I've created your example and it's giving `CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Action<int>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback` error. And `CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'btnClick' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`.

Comment: Your code doesn't really show how/where you want to use the return value.

Comment: Also `return 1;` will not compile either - `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Action<int>'`.

Comment: I didn't really attend anything at this point i have been trying to make it work.  I dont really need the method to return anything i just need to be able to pass it.  Someone on Gitter said to use T and it didnt work so i was grasping at straws assuming it needed a return var. Your right Onclick doesnt need return var

Comment: Hi, I just want to clarify something before I answer. You say you have a "razor page" but I see in your code sample you have a @code block, which are only used in Blazor components. So are you trying to pass a method from a Razor Page to a Blazor component? Or between two Blazor components?

Comment: @ChrisSainty I am using/learning Blazor under a week here.  I am also a back end developer making all this even more confusing.   If my terminology is incorrect please feel free to correct me in your answer.  I just assumed as the page .razor.   I am trying to pass it to a blazor component.

Comment: No worries @DalmTo, I just wanted to make sure I gave you the right information :)

Comment: Looking at your working example @DalmTo, there is no need for this code `ExternalMethod="@((param) => { btnClick(); })"`. You can just write `ExternalMethod="@btnClick"`. The `param` object is never used.

Comment: Good point!  I just updated it with your answer as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is an example of passing a method from a parent to a child and the child invoking it. As you don't require a return value I'm just using `Action` rather than `Action<T>`.

There are many ways you can make this code more compact, but I've gone for a more verbose example to hopefully show what's happening a bit better.

Parent Component:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<Child ParentMethod="@SayHello" />

@code {

    private void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

}
```

Child Component:

```
<h3>Child</h3>

<button @onclick="@InvokeParentMethod">Click Me!</button>

@code {

[Parameter] public Action ParentMethod { get; set; }

private void InvokeParentMethod()
{
    ParentMethod?.Invoke();
}

}
```

Comment: I had to set things public for it to work.  But thanks i like this option

Comment: how to send params to SayHello function from child ?

Comment: for an `async` function just pass `Task` instead.

Comment: delegate does not take 1 parameter

Answer (score 11):

This is because the Click event of btnClick isn't of the type `Action<int>` but actually `EventCallback<TIn>`. So change you'll need to change a few things around.

change ExternalMethod to

```cs
[Parameter]
protected EventCallback<int> ExternalMethod {get; set;}
```

and change the btnClick to

```cs
public void btnClick(int param) { /* code */ }
// and then set the razor to
<TestMethodPassing ExternalMethod="@btnClick"></TestMethodPassing>

// Or do it with a lambda in the razor

<TestMethodPassing ExternalMethod="@((param) => {/* code */ })"></TestMethodPassing>
```

There is a GitHub issue tracking the new Event Handling and Binding [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6351)

Comment: Correct. But adding an `InternalMethod()` as intermediate between onClick and the parameter might fit the requirements better.

Comment: I used the void option:   cannot convert from 'System.Action<object, System.EventArgs>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

Comment: @DaImTo I just rewrote my question

Comment: So there no way to pass a method other then doing it inline?

Comment: See @chris-sainty 's answer, this will fit your needs better

Comment: @DaImTo as far as I see, it should be possible. I just update my answer

Comment: It works but you missed the call to the method:  @((param) => { btnClick(); })

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

Page:

```
<TestMethodPassing ExternalMethod="@btnClick"></TestMethodPassing>
<label>@something</label>

@code {

    string something = "1";

    void btnClick()
    {
        something = "11";
    }
}
```

TestingMethodPassingModel:

```
[Parameter]
protected Action ExternalMethod { get; set; }
```

Component:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ExternalMethod" autofocus>External button</button>
```

### For your example (with `Action<int>`):

Page:

```
<TestMethodPassing ExternalMethod="@btnClick"></TestMethodPassing>

@code {

    void btnClick(int arg)
    {

    }
}
```

TestingMethodPassingModel:

```
[Parameter]
protected Action<int> ExternalMethod { get; set; }
```

Component:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ClickHandler" autofocus>External button</button>

@code {
    void ClickHandler()
    {
        ExternalMethod.Invoke(10);
    }
}
```