# How do I pass a Task<Func<string>> to a Blazor component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Imagine I have a (stupidly simple for clarity) Blazor component like this...

```cs
<code>@_html</code>

@code {
  private string _html = "";
}
```

In a parent component, a have a method as follows...

```cs
private async Task<string> GenerateHtml() {
  // Does something and returns some HTML
}
```

I would like it so that the parent component has a button, and when the user clicks the button, the return value from the `GenerateHtml()` method is set in the child component's `Html` local variable.

The reason for this is that I will be reusing the child component in many places, and each place will have its own way of generating the HTML it wants. I don't want to put that generating code in the child component, but am having trouble working out how to push it in.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831924/706346), but couldn't get it to work, partly because it has the button in the child component, and partly because the methods that generate the HTML will be async.

I also tried doing this with an `EventCallback`, but couldn't work out how to do that either.

Please can someone explain how I should do this? Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempts at following that answer and how it didn't work.  Also, you should probably reconsider this entire concept, as generating HTML strings won't work without using `MarkupString`, and using that type is extremely dangerous (in terms of XSS) unless you really know what you're doing and actively sanitize the generated HTML string.

Comment: @KirkWoll Will try and remember what I tried and add it in, but in the meantime, it's worth pointing out that the HTML being generated is NOT for display on the site. It is to be converted into PDF and stored as a document. Furthermore, the code generation is all internal to the site, using sanitised data from our own database (to which no-one else has access) so the HTML is totally under our control, no possibility of injection.

Comment: @KirkWoll Looking at it again, the code in that answer isn't at all wat I want. As I said in my question, it relies on there being a button on the child component. I don't want that. I need it so that the HTML can be generated from a method on the parent component, and passed in to the child component. I haven't a clue how to do that!

Comment: Can't you declare a property on the child component of type `Func<Task<string>>`?  i.e.  `<ChildComponent GenerateHtml="GenerateHtml" />` in the parent and `public Func<Task<string>> GenerateHtml { get; set; }` in the child?

Comment: @KirkWoll I'M SOOOOO STUPID!!!! The reason it wasn't working when I tried it was that I had the child's parameter of type `Task<Func<string>>`, not `Func<Task<string>>`!! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'll do it. :)  And sure, I'll post it as an answer in a moment.

Comment: May be a stupid question, and just an observation, but why are you generating the Html for a PDF document in the parent component?  If you're getting it from a database, why aren't you generating it in a service?  In general data activity belongs in services not components.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Perfectly reasonable question. When I said I was generating it in the parent component, it was to clarify that I don't want it generating in the child. In fact the HTML is generated in a service, which is called by the parent component.

Comment: No problem.  I see too many questions where the real issue is data in components.  Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, you'd like to provide a way for your parent's `GenerateHtml` method to be called from the child component.  This is easy enough to do.  You just need a delegate type that matches your method signature of `Task<string> GenerateHtml()`.  Since it returns a value it needs to be one of the `Func<>` variants, and since it takes no parameters you want `Func<Task<string>>`

Thus your child component should specify a parameter property of that type:

```
[Parameter]
public Func<Task<string>> HtmlGenerator { get; set; }
```

Then in the parent file, you can have the markup:

```
<ChildComponent HtmlGenerator="GenerateHtml" />
```

From there, the child component can generate the HTML by calling `HtmlGenerator()` or `HtmlGenerator?.Invoke()`.